# SIGABRT When going back to MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sigabrt

In my app, when the user presses a button, I want to produce information about that topic on a different view. E.G when the user presses the cat button, I want a new view to come up displaying the title and description. However, when they press dog it goes to the same view but it changes the information.

**firstViewController.h**

```
#import "secondview.h"

@interface ViewController :UIViewController 
{
    secondview *secondviewData;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textfield;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)secondview*secondviewData;

-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender; 

@end
```

**firstViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "secondview.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize secondviewData;

-(IBAction)passdata:(id)sender 
{
    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  
    self.secondviewData = second; 
    secondviewData.passedValue = @"dog Info";
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}

@end
```

**secondViewController.h**

```
@interface secondview :UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;  
    NSString *passedValue;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *passedValue;

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender;

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation secondview

@synthesize passedValue;

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender 
{
    ViewController *second = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    label.text = passedValue;
    [super viewDidLoad];
} 

@end
```

When I execute this code, it comes up with `SIGABRT`

Comment: Well, look at your console (Cmd-Shift-R).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your next view is segued from current view, you can use:
[image]

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nextViewSegue"]){

        nextViewController *nextViewObj  = segue.destinationViewController;
        nextViewObj.someNSString = @"the string you wanna to pass";
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nextViewSegue2"]){
        otherNextViewController *otherNextViewObj  = segue.destinationViewController;
        otherNextViewObj.someNSString = @"the string you wanna to pass";
    }
}
```

---

### ---------------------------**There is another way:**---------------------------

You can use global variable to pass parameters.

create a class

.h

```
   @interface iXxxxxxGlobal : NSObject
    {
        NSString *globalString;

    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *globalString;
    +(iXxxxxxGlobal *)getInstance;
    -(void) updateSetting;
    @end
```

.m

```
#import "iXxxxxxGlobal.h"

@implementation iXxxxxxGlobal

@synthesize globalString;

static iXxxxxxGlobal *instance = nil;


+(iXxxxxxGlobal *)getInstance
{
    if(instance ==nil)
    {
        instance = [iXxxxxxGlobal new];
        // Get initial value from Preferences and Settings.
        // Use <<Preferences and Settings>> 

    }
    return instance;
}

-(void)updateSetting
{
    //Do something to update <<Preferences and Settings>> 
}

@end
```

every time you use the global variable, you just need do this:

```
iXxxxxxGlobal *iXxxxxxGlobalObj=[iXxxxxxGlobal getInstance];
iXxxxxxGlobalObj.globalString = @"your string";
NSString *localString = iXxxxxxGlobalObj.globalString;
```

Comment: this is great, but I don's use storyboards. How would I do it then?

Comment: Then, you could use the second way: Global Variable.